# Opentelemetry- Typescript Project (Zipkin exporter)

Tags: typescript, zipkin, open-telemetry

I have a simple hello-world typescript project that I'm trying to set up opentelemetry on it. I want to send the traces to console and Zipkin.

I run the app but I don't get any tracer neither on console nor on Zipkin. I can't exactly pin-point what's the problem as I exported the init function (set up tracer in this function) and imported it in the app.ts file but for some reasons I can't get the tracers. There is no error when I run the app.

This is a simple project with two files: tracer.ts and app.ts

**tracer.ts**

```
import { NodeTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node';
import { SimpleSpanProcessor, BatchSpanProcessor, ConsoleSpanExporter, } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base'; 
import { Resource } from '@opentelemetry/resources'; 
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from '@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions'; 
import { ZipkinExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-zipkin'; 
import { registerInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation'; 
import { ExpressInstrumentation, ExpressRequestHookInformation } from 'opentelemetry-instrumentation-express'; 
import { HttpInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http';
    
const init = function (serviceName: string) {
    
//zipkin**************
    
//Specify zipkin url. defualt url is http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
    
const zipkinUrl = 'http://localhost'; 
const zipkinPort = '9411'; 
const zipkinPath = '/api/v2/spans'; 
const zipkinURL = ${zipkinUrl}:${zipkinPort}${zipkinPath};
    
const options = { 
    headers: { 
        'my-header': 'header-value', 
    }, 
    url: zipkinURL, 
    //serviceName: 'your-application-name',
    
    // optional interceptor
    getExportRequestHeaders: () => {
        return {
            'my-header': 'header-value',
        }
    }
    
} 
const traceExporter_zipkin = new ZipkinExporter(options);
    
////////*************End zipkin config */
    
const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({
    resource: new Resource({
        [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: serviceName
    }),
});
    
//export to console
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));
    
//export to zipkin
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(traceExporter_zipkin));
    
    
provider.register();
registerInstrumentations({
    instrumentations: [
        // new ExpressInstrumentation({
        //     requestHook: (span, reqInfo) => {
        //         span.setAttribute('request-headers',JSON.stringify(reqInfo.req.headers))
        //     }
        // }),
        new HttpInstrumentation(),
        new ExpressInstrumentation()
    ]
});
const tracer = provider.getTracer(serviceName);
    return { tracer };
}
    
export default init;

//end of tracer.ts*********
```

**********app.ts***********

```
import express from 'express'
import init from './tracer'; 

const { tracer } = init('app-services');
    
const app = express();
    
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{ res.send('Hello'); });
    
app.listen(3200, () => console.log('Server running'));

//end of app.ts*********
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your sample to make adjust according to the OpenTelemetry documentation:

**tracer.ts**

```
const opentelemetry = require('@opentelemetry/api');
const { registerInstrumentations } = require('@opentelemetry/instrumentation');
const { NodeTracerProvider } = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node');
const { Resource } = require('@opentelemetry/resources');
const { SemanticResourceAttributes } = require('@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions');
const { SimpleSpanProcessor, ConsoleSpanExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base');
const { ZipkinExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/exporter-zipkin');

const { ExpressInstrumentation, ExpressRequestHookInformation } = require('@opentelemetry/instrumentation-express');
const { HttpInstrumentation } = require('@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http');

module.exports = (serviceName) => {

  //Specify zipkin url. defualt url is http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
  const zipkinUrl = 'http://localhost';
  const zipkinPort = '9411';
  const zipkinPath = '/api/v2/spans';
  const zipkinURL = `${zipkinUrl}:${zipkinPort}${zipkinPath}`;

  const options = {
    headers: {
      'my-header': 'header-value',
    },
    url: zipkinURL,
    //serviceName: 'your-application-name',
    
   
    // optional interceptor
    getExportRequestHeaders: () => {
      return {
        'my-header': 'header-value',
      }
    }
  }
  const traceExporter_zipkin = new ZipkinExporter(options);

  const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({
    resource: new Resource({
      [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: serviceName,
    }),
  });

  provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));
  provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(traceExporter_zipkin));

  provider.register();

  registerInstrumentations({
    instrumentations: [
      // new ExpressInstrumentation({
      //     requestHook: (span, reqInfo) => {
      //         span.setAttribute('request-headers',JSON.stringify(reqInfo.req.headers))
      //     }
      // }),
      new ExpressInstrumentation(),
      new HttpInstrumentation()
    ],
  });

  return opentelemetry.trace.getTracer(serviceName);
};
```

And the the way the tracer was being called as well:
**app.ts**

```
require('./tracer.ts')('app-services');

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('Hello');
});

app.listen(3200, () => console.log('Server running'));
```

I've tested locally and I can see traces in the Console and in Zipkin.

Comment: Thank you Juliano for your help. Your solution worked like a charm. I can see that I missed a few small but critical steps.